# searching function in a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm working on a bool function that returns true if found a number on a linked list and false if not, unfortunately this code generates error

> *The ERROR:*
>
> **contains.c:24:1: error: control may reach end of non-void
> function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
> }
> ^
> 1 error generated.**

*Code:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 10

//make a struct called node
typedef struct nodes{
    int n;
    struct nodes* next;
}node;
//initiate a pointer to the node type
node* head=NULL;
//search function
bool search(int number){
    //traverse the list
    for(node* conductor=head;conductor!=NULL;conductor=conductor->next){
        if(conductor->n==number){
            return true;
            exit(0);
        }
    return false;
    }
}
//main function
int main(void){
    //make the linked list
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        node* new=malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(new==NULL){
            exit(0);
        }
    //initiate the new node
    new->n=i;
    new->next=head;
    head=new;
    }
    printf("The linked list is ready\n");
    printf("Please enter the number you are looking for:\n");
    int number;
    scanf("%i",&number);
    if(search(number)){
        printf("found\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Sorry, not found in the list. The list only contains:\n");
    }
    //printing the list components
    for(node* conductor=head;conductor!=NULL;conductor=conductor->next){
        printf("%i ",conductor->n);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

so, I don't know where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `search` has a return type `bool`. You have to return a `bool`. If the condition in the `for` loop is false, then nothing will be returned. This is what your compiler is complaining about. You probably wanted `return false;` **outside** the body of the `if`.

---

BTW, The `exit(0)` after `return true;` in the function `search` will never execute.

Comment: @MuhammadEbeid , You can still accept an answer by pressing the green checkmark beside them. You can accept *one* answer. It'll give some reputation to the answerer as well as the asker.

Answer (score 1):

`search` function should be like

```
bool search(int number){
    //traverse the list
    for(node* conductor=head;conductor!=NULL;conductor=conductor->next){
        if(conductor->n==number){
            return true;
        }
     }
     // If not found
     return false;
}
```

Place `return false;` statement out of `for` loop body. `exit(0);` in `for` is a statement with no effect and will never execute.